# Unix reading array and constructing a formatted output

Tags: shell, unix

```
mystring=fifth,forth,third,second,first
IFS=','  read -a ma <<< $mystring
con=""
for i in "${ma[@]}"; do
    val=A.$i=B.$i
    con="AND $val $con"
done
```

I want to read a array and construct output as below but I am getting error saying command not found at 6th line.

**Output needed** : AND A.first=B.first AND A.second=B.second AND ...........

Comment: change `“` to `"` might be work. `‘` to `'` too.

Comment: Yes worked, did not see that. Initially typed the code in rtf format then copied that into sublime text, there happened the mistake I guess.